# JENKINS with Tivoli Workload Scheduler Integration

Tags: jenkins, tivoli-work-scheduler

Is it possible to interface Jenkins with Tivoli Workload Scheduler, such as to trigger Jenkins to run a job requested by a TWS job stream ?

A trigger should wait for the Jenkins job to complete and return to TWS with a proper returncode.

But I havn't been able to find any info as yet!

PS. I'm just the interface guy and I have no Jenkins knowledge that so ever, so please any points of direction is welcome.